# Sum of Reciprocals

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I wonder if someone help me with this:

I have $\pi_1+\pi_2+ \pi_3 +\pi_4=A$  and  $\pi_1\pi_2\pi_3\pi_4=B$ where $\pi_i \;\forall i=1,2,3,4$ are unknown but $A,B$ are known numbers. Can I find for the following in terms of $A$ and $B$:
$1/\pi_1+1/\pi_2+1/\pi_3+1/\pi_4=?$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. For example, the pairs $$4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10, \; \; 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$$ and $$12 + 1 + (-1) + (-2) = 10, \; \; 12 \cdot 1 \cdot (-1) \cdot (-2) = 24$$ give different results for $\frac{1}{\pi_1} + \frac{1}{\pi_2} + \frac{1}{\pi_3} + \frac{1}{\pi_4}.$